# I want to run many SOAPUI project xmls using Gradle script, in Linux

Tags: gradle, soapui

I want to run the SOAPUI project xmls using Gradle script. The GRADLE script should read the project xmls from soapuiInputs.properties file and run automatically all. Please guide me step by step how to create Gradle script to run the SOAPUI projects in Linux server.

Note: We use SOAPUI version 5.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simple way is to call the SOAPUI [`testrunner`](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html) directly from gradle as `Exec` task, like you can do from cli.

In gradle you can define the follow tasks (Note that I try it on windows but to do the same on linux as you ask simply you've to change the paths):

```
// define exec path
class SoapUITask extends Exec {
    String soapUIExecutable = 'C:/some_path/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/testrunner.bat'
    String soapUIArgs = ''

    public SoapUITask(){
        super()
        this.setExecutable(soapUIExecutable)
    }

    public void setSoapUIArgs(String soapUIArgs) {
        this.args = "$soapUIArgs".trim().split(" ") as List
    }
}

// execute SOAPUI
task executeSOAPUI(type: SoapUITask){
    // simply pass the project path as argument, 
    // note that the extra " are needed
    soapUIArgs = '"C:/location/of/project.xml"'

}
```

To run this task use `gradle executeSOAPUI`.

This task simply runs a SOAPUI project, however `testrunner` supports more parameters which you can pass to `soapUIArgs` string in executeSOAPUI task, [take a look here](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/testrunner/cli).

Instead of this if you want to deal with more complex testing there is a gradle plugin to launch SOAPUI project, [take a look on it here](https://github.com/byte-shifter-ltd/soapui-gradle-plugin)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created a build.gradle by simply copy and paste your code after changing the testrunner.bat path and project.xml path. After that I have run it using command "gradle build" but came across with following error:

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created a build.gradle by simply copy and paste your code after changing the testrunner.bat path and project.xml path. After that I have run it using command "gradle build" but came across with following error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Task 'build' not found in root project 'SOAPUI'.

Is there anything I am missing here. Please guide me in each step since I am very new in Gradle.

Comment: @user2530711 the error is telling you that literally `build` task does not exists. You've to execute the `executeSOAPUI` task so instead of `gradle build` perform `gradle executeSOAPUI` since it's the name of defined task. `:)`

Comment: It worked...thank you so much. I wonder how to create the report. In ANt it creates testsuite.xml for logging pass fail...in Gradle is it possible? Will be there any index.html created? It would be great help if you guide me on this.

Comment: I have accepted your answer :) It was indeed helpful. I will open a separate question on report as suggested by you.

Comment: @user2530711 [In the link I put in the answer](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/testrunner/cli) there is the follow information `-f - Specifies the root directory, where the runner will save test result files. If the specified directory does not exist, it will be created. `, maybe it fits your report requeriment.

Comment: Sorry Sir I couldnot manage it in the code you have provided. IF you guide me by modifying the gradle script at least to show log folder is created and   Index.html like file is created. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @user2530711 to pass the parameters you only need to add them on `soapUIArgs` string inside `task executeSOAPUI`. Instead of `soapUIArgs = '"C:/location/of/project.xml"'` you've to use `soapUIArgs = '<arguments> "C:/location/of/project.xml"'.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir...but still unable to run it after giving the argument as instructed above. Anyway as suggested by you I have opened a new question here ...it would be good if you provide ur input there too. My new question :Need through guidance on Gradle script to execute soapui project xmls and generate report html

Comment: @user2530711 ok, I'll check it, however yesterday I did review the properties it can pass to soapui and I think that the properties needed for reports are only available for PRO version.